# Make Vscode on Gnome look like Windows?! (Removing the gnome titlebar)

Tags: visual-studio-code, gnome

### Intro

How to change VSCODE Gnome(41+) TopBar to look like the windows topbar?[image]

To:
[image]

Currently the [top bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FcAh.png) on GNOME takes a good amount of space. Also it doesn't look good(imo). How would i be able to change this?

Answer (score 14):

### How to set it up

If you open the Setting tab(`Ctr+,`) You can search for titlebar
[image]

Chane the `Window:Title Bar Style` from `native` to `custom` . Boom! Reload your vscode, and you have a window-like title bar

```
{
  "window.titleBarStyle": "custom"
}
```