reduce the gap between the sections (tabs, breadcrumbs, and the editor)
Title: How to Customize VS Code Layout with a Centered Search Bar and Breadcrumbs on the Left?
Question:
I've seen some users with a Visual Studio Code layout that has a single horizontal section where the search bar is centered, and the breadcrumbs are on the left side. This layout looks much cleaner and more organized than the default setup.
I've tried searching for solutions, but I haven't found a clear way to achieve this. Does anyone know how to customize the VS Code interface to get this layout?
Here’s what I’m looking to do:
Have a single horizontal section in the VS Code interface.
Center the search bar within this section.
Place the breadcrumbs on the left side of this section.
If anyone has done this before or knows how to modify the UI in this way, could you please share the steps or any necessary extensions/plugins?
Additional Context:
I’m using the latest version of Visual Studio Code. If there are any recommended extensions or custom CSS tweaks, I’m open to trying those out as wellenter image description here

at least partially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/72142915/11107541
